# MQ Console - Queue manager unavailable, despite it being active

Tags: ibm-mq, mq, web-console

I am testing a deployment of MQ 9.0.1 using Docker, and trying to administer this instance using the Web console. However I am receiving a warning when attaching widgets stating the "Queue manager unavailable".

[Warning messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUJNf.png)

In the console I can see my Queues are running and have created local queues and can run commands against them.

Also if I try to modify the Queue security records I get another error:

```
Failed to get authority recordsWMQWB0003E: The request could not be completed due to an internal web application server error.
```

Any thoughts or suggestions around this issue?

Comment: Are you following the steps in this document?  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q114495_.htm

Comment: Yep, I am working closely with some of the guys who wrote alot of the documentation around this, turns out it actually might be an issue with the Web Console running on Linux.

Comment: Please post a answer to your question if you do find a resolution to help people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There is no definitive fix for MQ9.0.1 but upgrading to use MQ9.0.2 will resolve issues with hosting MQ Console on linux.